# How to sanitize XML attributes values

Tags: sed, xml

I have the XML like this:

```xml
<string name="foo-bar">"bar-bar -bar"</string>
<string name="asdf_qwe-rty" translatable="false">"Lorem ipsum"</string>
```

Now, the `name` attribute can't contain `-` character, so I'd like to replace it with `_`.

```xml
<string name="foo_bar">"bar-bar -bar"</string>
<string name="asdf_qwe_rty" translatable="false">"Lorem ipsum"</string>
```

How can I do this, preferably with `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the XML document is well formed, you may use `xmlstarlet` to replace all occurrences of the character `-` in the `name` attributes of all `string` nodes with `_` like so:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//string/@name' -x 'translate(.,"-","_")' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <string name="foo_bar">"bar-bar -bar"</string>
  <string name="asdf_qwe_rty" translatable="false">"Lorem ipsum"</string>
  <string name="_test1_">name="-test1-"</string>
  <!-- <string name="-test2-">name="-test2-"</string> -->
</root>
```

(I've added a wrapping `root` node here to make the document well formed, and a couple of extra cases to show that we won't affect the node values, or contents of comments).

The `xmlstarlet` expression will find all the relevant attributes using the XPath expression `//string/@node`, and apply a simple translation of each `-` into `_` in each of these attribute's value.  The output is written to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution based on sed (or anything else that doesn't do proper XML parsing) will be wrong in a proportion of edge cases. For example, the solution from @Pitel:

(a) replaces the content of things that look like name attributes even if they are in comments or text rather than in a start tag

(b) also changes the content of an attribute named `firstname` or `lastname`

(c) fails to spot the attribute if it has whitespace around the equals sign.

So it might be adequate for one-off ad-hoc use, but don't put it into a production workflow. If you need something of production quality, use an XSLT transformation. It's not difficult:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="translate(., '-', '_')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: That looks very promising; you may want to explain (for the sake of the "non-XML-Gurus") how to apply this transformation to the XML file in question.

Answer (score -1):

```bsh
sed -r ':a; s/(name="[^-"]*)-/\1_/; ta'
```

Comment: Congratulations on solving the problem youself. You might consider explaining what your `sed` command does, so that others may learn more easily from your answer.